# How authority in Parity Proof of Authority chain choose to mine

Tags: ethereum, mining, parity

I implemented a Parity Proof of Authority private chain, running 2 authority nodes and 3 users nodes.

I managed to credit ether in the users nodes, and with one of the user node, i made a transaction.. and it worked !

The thing is, I don't understand how the authority mined this transaction, since they have to validate it, but how can they judge if the transaction has to be mined or not ?

I hope that I have been clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the explication of the AURA algorithm in this doc : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.03490.pdf

Pages 24 -> 26